# Unable to get the access token from KeyCloak

Tags: spring-boot, security, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to get the access token from the Keycloak server using postman.

I have been following this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak) and created the realm, user, role credentials as mentioned in the tutorial.

But when I make the request, it goes on indefinitely, without returning anything.

***edit:***
I tried grant_type as "password" and "client_credentials" as well. But no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the right way to get the Token from PostMan

```
https://<IP ADDRESS>:<PORT>/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

In Body Section select `x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
{
   "username": "username",
   "password": "password",
   "client_id": "APP-NAME",
   "grant_type": "password",
   "client_secret": "462fe347-d47f-4365-94ee-6aefff994ef2"
}
```

For more clear cut solution use like this 
[image]

```
If you want to from through `curl` command then use below command 
curl -X POST -k -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -i 'https://<IP>:<PORT>/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token' --data 'username=username&password=password&client_id=CLIENT-ID&grant_type=password&client_secret=462fe347-d47f-4365-94ee-6aefff994ef2'
```

**EDIT **

As discussed with OP in SO chat at last found solution ,OP was creating user with temp password so every-time user login it have to change the password thats why its failing .After OP changed the disable the option its started working
[image]

Comment: I don't see any difference in your solution and whta I tried. 
Can you please explain

Comment: @KshitizSharma Where is the client Secret in your case? If you ever stuck in rest api try same thing from `curl` command as well.

Comment: I set the access type as 'public' while setting up the realm. So, I didn't get the client_secret

Comment: @KshitizSharma try with the default client `admin-cli` is that working for you ? As i tested for same client in my setup its working fine . Or check your port is right ?

Comment: Actually, I am new to keyCloak. Can you suggest me, how can we do that?

Comment: @KshitizSharma How you are accessing your keycloak from GUI? What is ip-address/port to access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203016/discussion-between-kshitiz-sharma-and-subodh-joshi).

Answer (score 2):

In this example you can't use *client_credentials* because you don't have a client secret here you can read about [Client Credentials Grant](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/client-credentials/). It's also used mainly for server to server communication. 
You should not use password grant but for the examples sake its ok I guess. [Password Grant](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/)

so this is what I get
[image]

The question is how have you configured your spring-boot application?
Here are the application.properties like mentioned in the tutorial:

```
keycloak.realm=SpringBootKeycloak
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth/
keycloak.resource=login-app
keycloak.public-client=true
```

and this is how my SecurityConfig looks like

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(
        basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class,
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.management.HttpSessionManager"))
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*")
                .hasRole("user").anyRequest().permitAll();

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not even able to generate the token

Comment: I see an error in your screenshot. Realm does not exist. Do you still get that? Did you create this realm? also can you post your spring-boot configuration additionally change the grant_type to password

Comment: No, that was earlier. Now the request is not going through. Its just stuck at this stage. And I have not written any Spring boot code yet. I am just trying to get the token from postman

Comment: Well then how do you want it to work? You are asking Keycloak to give you an access token for what? In the tutorial it tells you to give a valid redirect url. It probably takes forever because the redirect url is not working. the thing is if the redirect url is not working then keycloak can't redirect you to this page with the valid access token

Comment: Oh I see. See, my use case is some outside service will get the access token for accessing the rest endpoints that I will be writing. In my application, I need to authenticate the token and accordingly give access to the resource

Comment: Then you need to tell keycloak were to redirect to. In this case your resource url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203021/discussion-between-kshitiz-sharma-and-alex-p).